# Wordpress deleting many unused categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I recently had a web site redesigned and migrated to another domain.  The new site uses Wordpress as a CMS for the whole site (it just managed the blog on the previous one).  Somehow in the process of setting up the new site, the designer added a whole slew of categories, 953 of them to be exact, and most of them have zero posts attached and will never be used.

I want to clear these zero-categories out, but it would take forever using the WP interface to do this, which only shows 20 at a time. Is there some way to do it with a MySQL operation?  I'm reluctant to just delete them from the categories table because I don't know how they are linked elsewhere in the DB. OTOH maybe if the category has zero posts it doesn't matter?

I know there is some WP method to safely do this because the categories page on the dashboard has to call it when you delete a category, but I can't figure out what it is from looking at the form.

Comment: Re your final paragraph, WordPress does not delete categories safely.  It does not check if items exist in the category.  It simply removes the deleted category from those items (as well as obviously removing the category), and if they have no other category puts them in 'Uncategorized'.  And it hasn't got any better despite 9 years of WordPress development since your post (though it's possible some safety net existed back then and development in this area has been retrograde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the 'screen options' button at the top of the control panel you can choose how many categories to display in the WP interface, then do the bulk-delete using the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.  But still with almost 1000 of the categories it would be nice to do it with a DB op if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is:

```sql
DELETE FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE taxonomy = 'category' AND term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM `wp_term_relationships`);

DELETE FROM `wp_terms` WHERE term_id NOT IN (SELECT term_id FROM `wp_term_taxonomy`);
```

Caution 1: Previously backing up your database might be a good idea.

Caution 2: This also deletes empty parent categories of non-empty child categories. If you have such cases you will have to update the `parent` column in `wp_term_taxonomy` table afterwards.

Comment: Most search results I find seem to suggest using WP Sheet Editor which looks just as cumbersome as what the OP was trying to avoid.  We have empty parent categories, so I will see if I can develop your solution to not delete those.  This has got to be the way forward, and I'm sure it's a common problem for which a one-click solution is possible.  Kudos for the cautions.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Dominik's answer to only remove empty CHILD categories:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE taxonomy = 'category' AND term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM `wp_term_relationships`) AND parent <> 0;
DELETE FROM `wp_terms` WHERE term_id NOT IN (SELECT term_id FROM `wp_term_taxonomy`);
```